How to get translation for translate view programmatically?
Assume I have two languages (English and Vietnamese) and already defined translations (label, description) in the translate view tab.



Is there a way to programmatically get the translation content via a specific language code and the view machine name, in a custom controller?

Typically, you would use a language detection method, where the default is a path prefix. When you visit the controller via /vi/path-to-controller, this is automatically translated. Or are you asking if you want to display only the translated configuration values in the screenshot?

I want to get translated configuration values in the screenshot and return its value via rest API but I solve this one already, thanks.

I can use this code to get the translated configuration values by langcode and  viewId.
$configTranslation = \Drupal::languageManager()
      ->getLanguageConfigOverride($langcode, 'views.view.' . $viewId);

